# Drawing objects on svg element using d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to make sense of a code that someone else has written and I have to complete. The code simply creates an svg element and appends it to an image, then hardcodes polygons on the image. Here is the code:

```
function drawPolys() {

  var canvas;

  canvas = d3.select("#map")
    .append("svg")
      .attr("width", 500)
      .attr("height", 500)
      .attr("id", "firstFloor");

  var coverageAreaID = 'room1';
  var content = '<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary view-cam-btn">View Camera</button> <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary set-dest-btn">Set Destination</button> <input type="hidden" name="coverage-area-id" value="'+coverageAreaID+'">';
  var polygon1 = [[60, 210], [60, 250], [140, 250], [140, 210]];
  var room1 = canvas.append("polygon")
    .attr("points", polygon1)
    .attr("class", "coverage-area")
    .attr("id", coverageAreaID)
    .attr("data-toggle", "popover")
    .attr('data-placement', 'top')
    .attr("data-content", content);
}
```

What I can't figure out is how the developer before me figured out the coordinates on the canvas. I can obviously start playing around with it and guess them until I get them right, but I have to draw about 40 of them, and it's gonna take hours...
Is there any way that I can access the canvas (in JS console for example) and find coordinates for where the polygons should end?

Comment: *"What I can't figure out is how the developer before me figured out the coordinates"*... He/she didn't, those are simply hardcoded values.

Comment: I understand that, I thought maybe there is a way to find those values, before hardcoding them (right now I'm putting in numbers, seeing where the polygon ends up and adjust them again and again).

Comment: Find *what* values?

Comment: [[60, 210], [60, 250], [140, 250], [140, 210]] in the code above, which are coordinates on the canvas.

Comment: I know that. But based on what? Please, have a good look at your question, what you are asking is not clear at all.